# How To Mask Ad Hoc (non-Parameter, non-Credential) Passwords in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I'm getting passwords back from Ansible as part of a Jenkins pipeline, then wanting to mask these passwords in shell scripts fired from Jenkins.

The difficulty is that these passwords are not pipeline parameters or Jenkins credentials.

I can see that the [mask passwords plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) allows regular expressions to be masked when pre-defined in Manage Jenkins. What I want to do here is define a regex (or literal string) to mask programmatically.

What I'd like is something like this:

```
def password = getPasswordFromAnsible()
maskPassword(password)
sh "applogin -u ${username} -p ${password}"
```

This `sh` script should generate the following in the console log:

```
sh "applogin -u my_username -p ******"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to disable command echoing before you run that particular sensitive command, and follow the logic using descriptive text instead:

```
sh '''
    echo "Attempting to login"
    set +x
    applogin -u ${username} -p ${password}
    set -x 
    echo "Logged in successfully"
'''
```